# Geo-Tags get lost when uploading to picasa website

Tags: geolocation, picasa, photos

The picasa website also offfers a map, where you can see the pictures of your album. Unfortunatly the upload doesnt support geo tags. They are no more with the pictures on picasa website ;(

You have the same issue? Maybe fixed it...?

Comment: Are you uploading directly through your phone, are you uploading through the Picasa software, manually uploading via the website? If the second option, what version of Picasa. (I don't think this is a phone issue.)

Comment: I am uploading through my phone. Select pictures in gallery - forward to - picasa

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. I just tried using the "Share" command to upload a geotagged photo from my Android phone to Picasa, and I can see the map on the Picasa website.

I am using an HTC Dream with Android 1.6